# fa icons not changing with ngClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to switch between check and uncheck box when user select the boxes
or unselect the box .

For that i am using :

```
<i class="far" ngClass="isItemSelected(item) ? fa-check-square : fa-square"></i>
```

> isItemSelected(item) return true or false

But, i cannot see the check box icon changing even on the ui true and false value is passed from the typescript code.

[image]

Can anyone help me.

Full Code Snippet:

Angular Side:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">
                        <div class="tiles">
                            <li>{{item}}</li>
                            <div class="deviceinfo-check-box" (click)="selectedItem(item)">                         
                              <i class="far" [ngClass]="isItemSelected(item) ? 'fa-check-square' : 'fa-square'"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

TypeScriptSide:

```
  selectedItem(item) {
        if (this.selecteditems.indexOf(item) < 0) {
            this.selecteditems.push(item);
        } else {
            this.selecteditems.splice(this.selecteditems.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    }



    isItemSelected(item) {
        return this.selecteditems.indexOf(item) < 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

[image]

> these true / false value i am getting using
>   {{isItemSelected(iotGateway)}} -->

URL: https://angular-m56o7e.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2):

In [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) key is the class you want to add and the value is the condition, which if is true then the class gets added otherwise it does not.

So you essentially needs to change your code to

```
<i class="far" 
  [ngClass]="{
    'fa-check-square': isItemSelected(item),
    'fa-square': !isItemSelected(item)
  }"
>
</i>
```

Comment: I cant see why it should not work until unless `isItemSelected` is doing something wrong. Can you check it once?

Comment: see the edited question Boolean value are changing when we click on check box but its not replaced by check-square icon.

Answer (score 2):

**update**

The problem is that FontAwesome replaces the `<i>` element by an `<svg>` element and this causes the bound classes to disappear. I'd suggest to use something like npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome that works around this problem.

**original**

The class name strings need to be put in quotes

```
<i class="far" [ngClass]="isItemSelected(item) ? 'fa-check-square' : 'fa-square'"></i>
```

**Hint**

You also should be aware that `isItemSelected(item)` is called every time change detection is run (which can be quite frequently) and this can harm the responsiveness of your app.

It's usually better to add the result of a computation to a property and bind to this property instead.

I assume `isItemSelected(item)` only does very little work, so it might be OK, but you should be aware that this can cause troubles.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `[]`.

Comment: please look at my full code i have edited in question

Comment: Does it show the checkmark if you add `class="fa-check-square"` statically? If it does add `<span>isSelected: {{isItemSelected(item)}}</span>` to check if `isItemSelected(item)` actually returns what you expect.

Comment: see the edited question boolean value are changing when we click on check box but its not replaced by check-square icon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165807/discussion-between-rohitesh-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Then it's a problem with the icons. The class name might be wrong or similar.

Comment: don't know but tried with some different name also that  also not wrking

Comment: can you see the changes with the provided link

Comment: The problem is that FontAwesome replaces the `<i>` element by an `<svg>` element and this causes the bound classes to disappear. I'd suggest to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome that works around this problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried the library you have mentioned. It is replacing <i> element with svg as well, therefore, ngclass isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I managed to fix it adding the `fa` to the class:

```
<i class="far fa" [ngClass]="isItemSelected(item) ? 'fa-check-square' : 'fa-square'"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the ngClass property i.e. use [] brackets like this.Also use single quotes with class names.

```
<i class="far" [ngClass]="isItemSelected(item) ? 'fa-check-square' : 'fa-square'"></i>
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

according to your issue,
we can define a variable in your (.ts) file that variable will have called to html file like this way:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="isItemSelected ? fa-check-square : fa-square">{{isItemSelected}}</fa-icon>
```

Answer (score -2):

also you can try this :

```
<i class="fa-{{status}}"></i>
```

and handle the value of status (check-square or square) in your component .